# Programming keyboard lights for DAW

Tags: keyboard, rgb, ableton-live

I am producing music (in Ableton Live) and will buy a pc keyboard with RGB lights, which will be used as such a software controller (play button, record button, etc.)

How can I program that while the software is recording, the recording button on the keyboard will flash? And while the software is playing, the play button on the keyboard will flash (Same as for the other function keys on the keyboard...)

By the way, If the keys can be flash at the BPM rate it would be great.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It will probably help if you link to the keyboard you want to buy..

Comment: This is not a specific keyboard. Maybe I'll order a custom build keyboard.

Comment: Ah I see. I would say it highly depends on the keyboard. As far as I know for most keyboards with individually assignable RGB backlights, the colors can only be managed with special companion software. You would need a keyboard that allows controlling the colors per key directly with external scripts. If that is possible I'm sure it would also be possible to find a way to link the Live API to the RGB lights via Max for Live or a control surface / remote script.